# Is this bluetooth configuration sufficient?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, yocto, bluez, openembedded

I have a Yocto/Open Embedded Linux build for a Gumstix Overo Y COM which I am trying to integrate bluetooth into (using Bluez4).

When I boot my image, the onboard bluetooth module (wilink 8) is unresponsive.  Is the configuration I outline below sufficient?  If not, what is missing?

The kernel, linux-firmware and bluez4 recipe append are from the meta-gumstix repo [fido] branch (https://github.com/gumstix/meta-gumstix) - one change I have made is the system uses sysvinit instead of systemd.

- 3.18 kernel with all patches and the defconfig:

  meta-gumstix/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-gumstix_3.18.bb

  meta-gumstix/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-gumstix-3.18/
- Firmware append recipe:

  meta-gumstix/recipes-kernel/linux-firmware_git.append

  meta-gumstix/recipes-kernel/linux-firmware/linux-firmware/
- Bluez4 recipe append:

  meta-gumstix/recipes-connectivity/bluez/bluez4_4.101.bbappend

  meta-gumstix/recipes-connectivity/bluez/files/

When I boot, this is all hcitool can tell me:

```
hcitool dev:
parallels@ubuntu:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
root@overo:~# hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device 
root@overo:~# /usr/sbin/hciattach -n ttyO1 texas
Initialization timed out.
```

If I start Bluez:

```
root@overo:~# dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
root@overo:~# bluetoothd -d
root@overo:~# rfcomm bind all
root@overo:~# dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   62.131408] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   62.131622] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   62.132080] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   62.132141] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   62.132263] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   62.190826] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   62.190856] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   62.190917] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   71.641448] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   71.641540] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   71.641601] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Then dbus tells me:

```
root@overo:~# dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
method return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=:1.2 reply_serial=2
   array [
      string "org.freedesktop.DBus"
      string ":1.0"
      string "org.bluez"
      string ":1.1"
      string ":1.2"
   ]
root@overo:~# 

(root@overo:~# cat introspect_bt.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def rec_intro(bus, service, object_path):
    print(object_path)
    obj = bus.get_object(service, object_path)
    iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable')
    xml_string = iface.Introspect()
    for child in ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string):
        if child.tag == 'node':
            if object_path == '/':
                object_path = ''
            new_path = '/'.join((object_path, child.attrib['name']))
            rec_intro(bus, service, new_path)

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
rec_intro(bus, 'org.bluez', '/org/bluez')
root@overo:~# 
)
root@overo:~# python introspect_bt.py 
/org/bluez
/org/bluez/1309
/org/bluez/1309/any
```

I would expect bluez to list an adapter such as /org/bluez/1309/hci0.  As neither hcitool or bluez seem to be able to locate my bluetooth module, am I missing something in the setup / configuration?

I'm more than happy to edit this to include any extra information that you might find useful.

Thanks!

---

Edited with further info:

@parthiban-n - 
Bringing the adapter up doesn't work

```
root@overo:~# hciconfig hci0 up
Can't get device info: No such device
```

& I don't know where the adapter sits (I think this is the root problem - bluez doesn't seem to know anything about the hardware and doesn't have an adapter for it).  Is this something that I can configure myself, or should bluez automatically recognise the module?
I used bluez5 initially with the same results, before downgrading to bluez4 (I'm loath to change back as switching bluez version is a complete delete-cache & rebuild, around 6 hours!).  I imagine that as hciconfig & hcitool can't communicate with the BT module the problem was unlikely to be with bluez, AFAIK hci**** don't use bluez for their operation.

---

@aksonlyaks - 
The module is not USB connected, it's an onboard combined WIFI/BT module - the Wilink8 WL1831MOD which seems to use a combined driver for WIFI & BT.  The WIFI works fine, so I think it's OK from the driver side of things.  Here's some output from /proc/modules & dmesg which looks good to me, but I've posted it up  in case there is anything obviously missing:

```
root@overo:~# cat /proc/modules
rfcomm 34100 0 - Live 0xbf2d3000
bnep 10602 2 - Live 0xbf2cc000
bluetooth 300191 8 rfcomm,bnep, Live 0xbf270000
ipv6 367991 16 [permanent], Live 0xbf1ff000
ctr 3441 2 - Live 0xbf1fb000
ccm 7252 2 - Live 0xbf1f6000
ft6206 3532 0 - Live 0xbf1f2000 (O)
arc4 1688 2 - Live 0xbf1ee000
wl18xx 81650 0 - Live 0xbf1d1000
wlcore 177003 1 wl18xx, Live 0xbf198000
mac80211 478003 2 wl18xx,wlcore, Live 0xbf0fb000
cfg80211 408851 3 wl18xx,wlcore,mac80211, Live 0xbf06a000
rfkill 19564 4 bluetooth,cfg80211, Live 0xbf060000
wlcore_sdio 3947 0 - Live 0xbf058000
twl4030_madc 9173 0 - Live 0xbf052000
industrialio 27152 1 twl4030_madc, Live 0xbf045000
fpgaDrv352 13275 2 - Live 0xbf03e000 (O)
usb_f_ecm 8379 1 - Live 0xbf037000
pwm 6671 0 - Live 0xbf031000 (O)
fpgaCfgDrv 5623 0 - Live 0xbf02c000 (O)
g_ether 3375 0 - Live 0xbf027000
usb_f_rndis 21372 2 g_ether, Live 0xbf01c000
u_ether 14284 3 usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xbf014000
libcomposite 46775 3 usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xbf000000
```

I think wl18xx & wlcore are the main driver components for the WL1831MOD.

```
root@overo:~# dmesg | grep -i wl
[    2.430389] twl 0-0048: PIH (irq 23) chaining IRQs 339..347
[    2.430999] twl 0-0048: power (irq 344) chaining IRQs 347..354
[    2.437225] twl_rtc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:rtc: Power up reset detected.
[    2.437805] twl_rtc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:rtc: Enabling TWL-RTC
[    2.442840] twl_rtc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:rtc: rtc core: registered 48070000.i2c:twl@48 as rtc0
[    2.511505] twl4030_gpio twl4030-gpio: gpio (irq 339) chaining IRQs 355..372
[    2.513275] gpiochip_add: registered GPIOs 492 to 511 on device: twl4030
[    2.524597] twl4030_usb 48070000.i2c:twl@48:twl4030-usb: Initialized TWL4030 USB module
[    2.531158] input: twl4030_pwrbutton as /devices/68000000.ocp/48070000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0048/48070000.i2c:twl@48:pwrbutton/input/input0
[    2.534881] twl4030_keypad 48070000.i2c:twl@48:keypad: OF: linux,keymap property not defined in /ocp/i2c@48070000/twl@48/keypad
[    2.547119] twl4030_keypad 48070000.i2c:twl@48:keypad: Failed to build keymap
[    2.554748] twl4030_keypad: probe of 48070000.i2c:twl@48:keypad failed with error -2
[    2.760864] twl_rtc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (946684800)
[    8.107849] twl4030_madc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:madc: clk disabled, enabling
[   11.101715] wlcore: wl18xx HW: 183x or 180x, PG 2.2 (ROM 0x11)
[   11.224395] wlcore: loaded
[   19.257476] wlcore: PHY firmware version: Rev 8.2.0.0.195
[   19.375305] wlcore: firmware booted (Rev 8.8.0.0.13)
[   23.282714] wlan0: authenticate with 30:b5:c2:66:4c:04
[   23.306152] wlan0: send auth to 30:b5:c2:66:4c:04 (try 1/3)
[   23.327819] wlan0: authenticated
[   23.338958] wlan0: associate with 30:b5:c2:66:4c:04 (try 1/3)
[   23.345367] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 30:b5:c2:66:4c:04 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[   23.390258] wlan0: associated[   23.624877] wlcore: Association completed.
```

It looks like the driver comes up and then there are some wlan related messages, nothing specific to bluetooth operation or intialisation that I can see.

Comment: Can you try bringing the adapter up? Use this command `hciconfig hci0 up`, if your adapter sits as hci0. One more recommendation is to use BlueZ5 instead of BlueZ4. BlueZ4 is very old AFAIK.

Comment: Also, try to see if your linux has driver for your bluetooth module. Check this in dmesg. It could be possible that your build might be missing driver for the module itself. You can also confirm this by checking /proc/modules. Look there for btusb if your own board module connects through usb.